# R; Conditionally replacing string values in a table to int

Tags: r

I have a huge data set which I have read as a table:

```
data = read.table("C:\\test\\test.tsv", header=TRUE)

View(data)
a   b   c
1   11  user
2   22  organization
3   33  user
4   44  user
5   55  organization
6   66  group
7   77  group
...
```

Now, I want to change the values in column c to 0 (if they are user), 1 (if they are organization) or 2 (if they are group):

```
a   b   c
1   11  0
2   22  1
3   33  0
4   44  0
5   55  1
6   66  2
7   77  2
...
```

I tried this command:

```
data$c[data$c=="organization"] <- 1
```

But I got this warning:

> Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, data$c == "ORG", value =
>   c(2L, NA, 2L, NA)) :   invalid factor level, NA generated

and all the "organization" values converted to NA.

I am aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170417/several-substitutions-in-one-line-r) which my question is reported a duplicate of, but here, we have a **table**, not **data frame**. In addition, the conversion is from String to integer.

Comment: `data$c <- as.numeric(data$c == "organization")`

Comment: @josilber `as.integer` seems better, or obfuscating shortcut `+(data$c == "organization")`

Comment: Just found the answer:         data$c <- ifelse(data$c=="user", 0, ifelse(data$c=="organization", 1, 2))